# adding type Date and type Int in Swift?

Tags: swift

This is a very simple question but it's been bugging me. According to Swift, it's not possible for values of different types to be added together (like String and Int), how's it possible that the following code works even though it adds type Date and type Int together?

```
let someDate = Date() + 2828282
```

Answer (score 3):

On the documentation page for [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) you can see
that there is a [`+`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/2293740)
operator taking a `Date` and `TimeInterval` as operands:

> Returns a date with a specified amount of time added to it.
>      `static func +(lhs: Date, rhs: TimeInterval) -> Date`

So you can add a `TimeInterval` (which is a type alias for `Double`)
to a `Date`, but not an `Int`. Your code compiles because `2828282`
is a "number literal" and the compiler can infer the type from
the context as `Double`.

This would not compile:

```
let delta = 2828282 // an Int
let someDate = Date() + delta
// error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Date' and 'Int'
```

You would have to convert the `Int` to a `TimeInterval/Double`

```
let delta = 2828282 // an Int
let someDate = Date() + TimeInterval(delta)
```

or make `delta` a `Double`:

```
let delta = 2828282.0 // a Double
let someDate = Date() + delta
```

Answer (score 1):

> According to Swift, it's not possible for values of different types to be added together (like `String` and `Int`)

Unlike in many other languages, there is no automatic conversions between numeric types, a.k.a *numeric promotions*, and the majority of pre-defined numeric operators expect both operands to be of the same type.

However there is nothing in Swift to prevent operators being declared with different type operands, and your example `Date() + 2828282` is one example where a pre-defined operator is defined with different operand types.

So the difference with Swift is that is lacks automatic numeric promotions, and that combinations such `realVar + intVar` are not pre-defined.

In many other languages the combination is not pre-defined either, but numeric promotions exist, so the example is compiled as `realVar + real(intVar)`.

HTH